# A polynomial basis of Cn[X]

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, change-of-basis

Let $\mathrm{c}_{0}, \ldots, c_{n}$ be pairwise disctinct complexes. I proved that $\left(\left(X-c_{i}\right)^{n}\right)_{0 \leq i \leq n}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}_{n}[X]$ by induction.

1) Do you know another way to prove that those are linearly independent elements?

2) How would you prove it's a set of generators of $\mathbb{C}_{n}[X]$? ( without using 1, obviously)

3) I can't find the decomposition of 1 on this basis, I tried with the matrix method, but I couldn't conclude.

Comment: The answer to question 2 is immediate after 1....

Comment: I want a method for 2 without using 1, obviously.

Comment: Do you know anything about linear algrebra?

Comment: More then you could imagine :)

Comment: 3) is indeed solved easily using [these matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: How? I can't see the obviousness